# Should i always call a module into a var or execute immediately in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, i am coming from a LAMP stack and all this new js is quite new to me.

I have written an email sending module for my little app which is executed as follows:

```
var emailer = require( '../../app/emailer.js');
emailer({
    tplName : 'activationEmail',
    tplVariables : {name:'john',activationLink:'bob'},
    sendToEmail: 'john@gmail.com',
    sendToName: 'John',
    fromEmail : 'noReply',
    subject: 'Activation email'
});
```

Now this works just fine however i am not sure what is better (as i am missing some fundamental nodejs knowledge), to run as above or run as this:

```
require( '../../app/emailer.js')({
    tplName : 'activationEmail',
    tplVariables : {name:'john',activationLink:'bob'},
    sendToEmail: 'john@gmail.com',
    sendToName: 'John',
    fromEmail : 'noReply',
    subject: 'Activation email'
});
```

As you can see here this is triggereing an activation email, the emailer module  is being called from within a passport module.

My question, should I 'require' the module into a var then reference the var later, or require the emailer module each time i need it.. i'm not sure what the difference is..

A NooB Q i know, but i can't find a solid answer on google.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: I think it's more of a js question as opposed to Node (imho).  I typically declare all var's at the top of the file (if using them down in the rest of the file).  reason for this is that if you need to ever use emailer down in the file, it makes it easy to reuse.  Also, it just looks much cleaner to import everything at the top, then usage below it.  Also , take a [look at this](http://www.mircozeiss.com/node-js-require-s-best-practices/) to get some idea on best practices (although this is slightly opinionated)

Comment: if you're using it more than one, cache it to avoid the lookup and function call overhead. require itself caches in ram, so it's not slow to re-call it, but it is more work than simply accessing an existing variable.

Comment: OK thanks.. then i suppose i have a related but noobier Q. The require() in the above Q case... this is being required once on initial starting of the app right and not each time a request is made that would run the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no benefit to storing it in a variable unless you will use that module more than once.

If I am writing a very short nodejs project, and need to use a single module just one time, I often don't bother to store it in a variable, I'd just do what you have done.

However, if I know I will be reusing that module, I store it, so that when reusing my program isn't slowed by the `require` lookup every time.

Also, if I am using other modules as well, I like to declare everything at the top of my file, even one-time modules.

```
var fs   = require('fs'),            // will use more than once
    http = require('http'),          // will use more than once
    qr   = require('qr-codes'),      // will use more than once
    ip   = require('ip');            // will only use once
```

I just think it looks neater.